# How to get a specific row by worksheet and rowindex in excel file

Tags: c#, excel, row, cell

I need to choose a specific cell in my excel file via using openXML:

```
Worksheet workSheet = workSheetPart.Worksheet;
Cell cell = GetCell(workSheet, "B", 2);


private static Cell GetCell(Worksheet worksheet,
  string columnName, uint rowIndex)
    {
        Row row = GetRow(worksheet, rowIndex);

        if (row == null)
            return null;

        return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => string.Compare
               (c.CellReference.Value, columnName +
               rowIndex, true) == 0).First();
    }

private static Row GetRow(Worksheet worksheet, uint rowIndex)
    {
        var test = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().
          Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First(); //Here is the problem. 

return worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().
          Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();
    }
```

When debugging I have noticed that RowIndex is null, so this is causing the problem I guess in the linq query

Answer (score 0):

Use ElementAt...

```
var test = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>().ElementAt(rowIndex);
```

Comment: This won't work if the document contains any empty rows at or before rowIndex due to Excel's sparse storage structure.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a row, you have to set the Row index value for each row you added to the excel.

```
Row headerRow = new Row() { RowIndex = new UInt32Value(1) }; //Here I used as 1(one), use accordingly
```

When you create a cell, you have to set the CellReference value for each cell you created.

```
  Cell cell = new Cell() { };
  cell.CellReference = new StringValue("A1");
  cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
  cell.CellValue = new CellValue("Test value");
```

If the Row index and  cell reference is not set, the values will be null when you query among it.

Some other useful methods for using in excel

```
 //To get the CellReference
 private static string GetExcelCellReference(uint columnNumber, uint rowNumber)
    {
        return $"{GetExcelColumnName(columnNumber)}{rowNumber}";
    }

    //To get the excel column name using column number
    private static string GetExcelColumnName(uint columnNumber)
    {
        int dividend = (int)columnNumber;
        string columnName = String.Empty;
        int modulo;

        while (dividend > 0)
        {
            modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
            columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
            dividend = (int)((dividend - modulo) / 26);
        }

        return columnName;
    }

    //To get the excel column name from cellname or cellreference number
    private static string GetColumnName(string cellName)
    {
        // Create a regular expression to match the column name portion of the cell name.
        Regex regex = new Regex("[A-Za-z]+");
        Match match = regex.Match(cellName);

        return match.Value;
    }

    //To get the row index from cell name or cell reference number
    private static uint GetRowIndex(string cellName)
    {
        // Create a regular expression to match the row index portion the cell name.
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
        Match match = regex.Match(cellName);

        return uint.Parse(match.Value);
    }
```